# Help: HOWTO Test Android App from within Emulator with Different Mobile Web Broswer Engines?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have developed a mobile application using jQuery Mobile.   I have it working in the emulator using the default web browser engine.  Now, I want to test the app using the different browsers engines available on mobile devices.  I have seen this accomplished from other developers, such as Opera, Chrome, or Safari.  What is happening is these different browsers are being pointed to the Android emulator that is running the application.

Can anyone provide a link on how this is accomplished so I may follow the steps? I have searched the net and I can seem to find any solid information that explains this well enough for me to follow.

Thank you for reading my post.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the emulator to browse the web and go to websites with browser packages for you to install other apps in your virtual phone.

Alternatively you can use DDMS to transfer the .apk files to your virtual mobile phone, and then install them without using internet on emulator.

Then, when you have some application associated with a specific file type or operation, typically Android asks you which one you want to use, with a popup, and allows you to also set a default one for that file type/action.